# What is type=argparse.FileType('rb') in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I am looking at other person's Python code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Recover files from an NTFS volume")
parser.add_argument('--mft', type=argparse.FileType('rb'), help='Use given file as MFT')
```

and find this `type` argument a bit strange for a classic C++/Delphi/C# developer.

I can imagine what `type=int` is, but `type=argparse.FileType('rb')` ... ?!

I can suppose that it is a kind of "all in one" operation that takes a string argument and instantly uses it as a file name for opening a file for reading and returns its file variable (descriptor). Am I right?

The documentation doesn't reveal the mechanisms.

Comment: Your guess is right. You can also peek at the source code for that type to figure out how it does its thing.

Comment: It's all explained in the [documentation for `argparse`'s `FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects). And you can look at the [CPython's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/argparse.py#L1260). It's just a thin wrapper for `open`

Comment: `FileType` was provided as a convenience when writing small scripts that take input and output files.  In newer Python versions we are encouraged to open files in a `with` context, so they are open only as long as we really need them.  So feel free to accept plain filenames, and do your own open/close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` and `FileType` work the same, although it may not be obvious at first. The `type=` parameter is just a callable used to create the object assigned to the parameter. `argparse` takes the original string parameter and, if `type` is not `None`, calls whatever object is there to create the value assigned to the parameter.

If you use `type=int`, then `int()` is called. But you can use any callable - `argparse` doesn't care - it just calls whatever you supply. You could use `type=open` and then `argparse` would call `open()` and you'd get a character mode file opened read-only.

You can use the `__call__` magic method in your own classes to make callable class instances. That's what happens here. `argparse.FileType` creates an object that records file open parameters. When called with a single string via the `__call__` method, it will open and return a file with those parameters. Its like `open` but lets you control the parameters.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists("deleteme")
False
>>> file_type = argparse.FileType("wb")
>>> file = file_type("deleteme")
>>> file
<_io.BufferedWriter name='deleteme'>
>>> os.path.exists("deleteme")
True
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. In Python there is obviously no separation of concerns :)

Comment: Interesting point, but I think the opposite is true. Suppose you have an integer parameter but the user inputs "foo". You'd expect an argument parser to display a message and exit the program without other programmer intervention. The exact same thing happens here if an invalid path is given. Its arguably better than opening the file yourself and having a different error path and error message for one bad argument verses another. argparse is converting and validating input parameters in both cases - one concern.

Comment: You can do most of your input parameter validation in the argument parser with your own custom classes and functions. Its all in one place and has a common outcome for the user.